# Create a pie chart in Splunk with the percentage of records with certain message size

Tags: logging, charts, functional-programming, splunk

I'm looking to create a pie chart of the percentage of messages that are received within a span of message bytes.

Given that each record in splunk has a `message_bytes` attribute, which is the size of the message in bytes, I'm looking to find the percentages of messages across a span of megabytes.

i.e If I have 100 messages:

- 20 of them are between 0 - 1024*1024*1024 (0-1 MB)
- 30 of them are between 2-3MB
- 50 of them are between 6-7MB

I'd like to output a pie graph that displays the 20%, 30% and 50% accordingly.

My search is currently:

`group="SOURCE"  | eval size=message_bytes  | bucket message_bytes span={some_span_size} | stats count(size) by message_bytes`

But my results are looking invalid

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
group="SOURCE" 
| eval MB = messages_bytes/(1024*1024)
| eval size_bucket = case(MB<=1,"small",
                          MB>=2 and MB<=3,"medium",
                          MB>=6 and MB<=7,"large"
                          1==1,"Other")
| stats count by MB
```

But I suspect that this is not really what you want. Try this

```
group="SOURCE" 
| eval MB = round(messages_bytes/(1024*1024),2)
| eval pie_group = ceiling(MB/2)
| stats count min(MB) as minMB max(MB) as maxMB by pie_group
| eval pie_group=tostring(minMB) + " to " + tostring(maxMB)
| table pie_group count
```

You could vary the `pie_group` calculation as needed.